# flatpak install org.telegram.desktop gives the Error: No remote refs found

Tags: kubuntu, kde, telegram

OS says **No remote refs found**:

```
flatpak install org.telegram.desktop
Looking for matches…
error: No remote refs found similar to ‘org.telegram.desktop’
m@kubuntu:~$ flatpak install org.telegram.desktop
```

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.4.0-60-generic
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose you have missed *flathub* installation source from commandline:

`flatpak install flathub org.telegram.desktop`

The command above will work if you have added this installation source before by running:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

---

Reference: https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.telegram.desktop

Comment: For some reason starting works not anymore: not found for `telegram` or 
`org.telegram.desktop`